# How to generate data-automation-id for each option dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-test

I'm new to Angular. I've written some code. It contains two dropdown menus. I'm using simple `select` and `option` tag of HTML. It is working perfectly. But the QA team says they ain't able to test it. How do I add `data-automation-id` for each option separately in runtime. I'm reading options from the same array using `ngFor`. Here is my code.

**mycalendar.component.html**

```
<select data-automation-id="timeselection-mode-primary">
  <option *ngFor="let mode of modes">
      {{ mode }}
  </option>
</select>

...

<select data-automation-id="timeselection-mode-secondary">
  <option *ngFor="let mode of modes">
      Previous {{ mode }}
  </option>
</select>
```

There're no reactive forms involved. Plain HTML tags.

**mycalendar.component.ts**

```
modes=['Year', 'Quarter', 'Sprint'];
```

Can someone please tell me how do i generate automation ids in runtime. Or am I asking a wrong question and wasting everyone's time. Please suggest an alternative in that case.

Comment: Do you want to set ```automation-id``` to the ```select``` or  each ```option``` ?? Does this example solves your issue https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lxfsua

Comment: @ManirajMurugan. This will work. Please post this as an answer for me to accept. Thanks :-)

Comment: Posted as answer.. Glad to help you..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make data attributes to options dynamically, try adding attributes to the options with `[attr.data-*]`.. In your case like below.

```
<option *ngFor="let mode of modes; let i = index;" [attr.data-automation-id]='i'>
      {{ mode }}
</option>
```

[**Working example here...**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lxfsua)

Comment: But there are two dropdowns. It will ceate same indexes for both starting from 0,1, 2.

Comment: I tried `[attr.data-automation-id]="options_+'i'"` for first dropdown and  `[attr.data-automation-id]="previous_options_+'i'"` but I'm getting `data-automation-id="undefinedi"`

Comment: @Tanzeel, You need to do like this ```[attr.data-automation-id]="'options_'+i"``` if you want to append a string in dynamic value.. Edited example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wrjrnk

Comment: Oh. I realized i messed up with inverted commas. So stupid of me. It's working now.

Comment: Hi Maniraj, I'm sorry to tell you this, but this approach is not accepted by my tech lead. Can you please look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60070086/how-to-trim-whitespaces-while-setting-data-automation-id-dynamically

Answer (score 1):

Put your select in an `ngFor` that iterates two times, and give its index as `data-automation-id`.
Or, you can call a function that generates random id `data-automation-id="generateRandom()"`

Comment: This sounds good Nitika. I'll try this. But I'm not sure whether my code tech lead will be very happy during the code review. I'll update you.