# How to trim whitespaces while setting data-automation-id dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing

I'm making a simple timeselection widget in Angular to compare our current performance with previous performance. My widget contains two `dropdown` lists and some buttons and input fields (forget about buttons and input fields). My question is regarding the testing of those dropdown. Here is my code:

**timeselector.component.html**

```
<select data-automation-id="timeselection-mode-primary">
  <option *ngFor="let mode of modes" [attr.data-automation-id]="'options_' + mode">
    {{ mode }}
  </option>
</select>

<!--some input fields and toggle button goes here-->

<select data-automation-id="timeselection-mode-secondary">
  <option *ngFor="let mode of modes" [attr.data-automation-id]="'previous_options_' + mode">
    Previous {{ mode }}
  </option>
</select>
```

And both of them are reading `modes` from the same array in my typescript:

**timeselector.component.ts**

```
modes=['Calendar year', 'Year-to-date', 'Quarter', 'Monthly Pipe', 'Weekly Sprint']
```

My problem is, `Calendar year`, `Monthly Pipe` and `Weekly Sprint` are having spaces. So, this way my `data-automation-id` will be as follows:

`options_Calendar year`, `options_Monthly Pipe`, `options_Weekly Sprint`.

To solve this problem, I introduced `index` values with each option like this:

```
<option *ngFor="let mode of modes; let i=index"
                [attr.data-automation-id]="'options_' +i">
```

and

```
<option *ngFor="let mode of modes; let i=index"
                [attr.data-automation-id]="'previous_options_' +i">
```

This worked also. But my tech lead is not very happy with this index approach. She wants me to use `mode` only. She told me to use `truncate`, `trim` or whatever solution there is, but no indexes.

I know how to use methods like `truncate`, `trim`, `subString`. But I cant figure out how to do it in runtime with data-automation-id. I tried some other solutions but didn't work. Please help me.

The widget looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove white space in between a string, you can pass the string to a function and get it `split` (with white space) and `join` (with dash - ) like,

```
  getModifiedText(mode){
    const splitMode = mode.split(' ');
    const joinMode = splitMode.join('-')
    return joinMode;
  }
```

So modify the files like,

**component.html**:

```
<select data-automation-id="timeselection-mode-primary">
  <option *ngFor="let mode of modes;" [attr.data-automation-id]="'options_'+ getModifiedText(mode)">
      {{ mode }}
  </option>
</select>
```

**component.ts**:

```
  getModifiedText(mode){
    const splitMode = mode.split(' ');
    const joinMode = splitMode.join('-')
    return joinMode;
  }
```

I have given `splitMode.join('-')` , you could change this part as per your need.. Eg: `splitMode.join('_')`..

And working [**Stackblitz here...**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sjfpv1)

Comment: This is super awesome bro. Actually I was also going to do the same. But then I thought when there are pre-built methods then we should use them. But now I'm going to use this only. Let me know when you're in Bangalore. I'll get you a nice lunch  :-)

Answer (score 1):

How about delegating the generation of `data-automation-id` to the controller part (TS file) rather than the template (HTML)?

Say in `timeselector.component.ts`, instead of having

```
modes=['Calendar year', 'Year-to-date', 'Quarter', 'Monthly Pipe', 'Weekly Sprint']
```

have this instead:

```
modes = {
  name: 'Calendar year',
  id: 'options_calendar_year',
  ...
}
```

then in `timeselector.component.html` you can have:

```
<select data-automation-id="timeselection-mode-primary">
  <option *ngFor="let mode of modes" [attr.data-automation-id]="mode.id">
    {{ mode.name }}
  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: I really appreciate this solution. Let me implement this, get it reviewed and tested. Then I'll come back to you. Please give me 10 mins :-)

Comment: I had a word with tech lead. We cant change the structure of `modes`. It is coming from an external source. And also in future releases there can me more options, so there will be too much of hard coding for `mode.id`.

Comment: 1) Yes, you can't change it from the external source but you can change the "presentation" of `modes` in your code. When you try to get the value upon selection, just get what's necessary. 2) You don't have to hard-code, you can just make a function that would auto-generate the ID based on the name of the mode and call that function. :) It would also be helpful if you post the code on how you'd use `attr.data-automation-id`